# Extract jar archive from oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using oracle 11 like database and I have an jar or some java classes wired within my database. Now I want to extract it from the database. Using sql developer I have the following situation:

[image]

Is there a way to exctract them from my database?

Comment: you can try using `expdp` with `include=JAVA_CLASS`

Comment: Can you give me an example to how to invoke this command correctly?

Comment: I post the example i tried.I hope this help

Comment: Check this new solution